# In the Vedas, does the word 'manuṣya' ever have a special meaning?

Tags: vedas, sanskrit

The Sanskrit word '[manuṣya](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%A8%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%B7%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AF)' ordinarily means 'a man, a human being'.

In the four Vedas (Rigveda, Yajurveda, Samaveda & Atharvaveda), are there any situations or contexts where the word '[manuṣya](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E0%A4%AE%E0%A4%A8%E0%A5%81%E0%A4%B7%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%AF)' is used to describe, not merely the anatomically '[homo sapiens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homo_sapiens)' species, but a higher moral character or a higher spiritual mentality?